# Getting "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address." errror

Tags: c#

```
string email = "select seller.emailid from seller inner join cars on seller.sid=cars.sid where cars.carid='" + lbllid + "' ";
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage("****@gmail.com", email, "Ruby Cabs Email Confirmation", Environment.NewLine + " This is an email automated sevice." + Environment.NewLine + "Your car has been approved. Thank you for taking out time to fill the data." + Environment.NewLine + "Regards," + Environment.NewLine + "Ruby Cabs");
            MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
            NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential("****@gmail.com", "****");
            SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
            mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            mailClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication;
```

I have checked the query on sql server and it works fine. Can any one tell whats the issue

Comment: Well obviously an SQL query isn't a valid email address, is it?

Comment: it is valid. I use it all the time.

Comment: You're expecting the `MailMessage` class to recognize a SQL query and execute it?  That is *not* going to work.

Comment: I dont see here ```string email = "select seller.emailid from seller inner join cars on seller.sid=cars.sid where cars.carid='" + lbllid + "' ";``` a valid email

Comment: Please read the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Samsam I'm sure its a valid query.  It is not, however, a valid email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting a SQL query in the email field when calling `new MailMessage(...)`.

You'll need to **run** the query against your SQL server, get the result set, extract the email address from said result set, and use THAT as your email address.

The debugger is your friend.

Comment: Also, you might want to paramterise that query - as it stands you are a few lines of code away from a massive SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @AntP **I** would put it in a stored procedure, and put the message text in the database, as well. At the very least use `string.Format()` rather than concatenating everything. I'd give even odds that it's directly in a codebehind, as well.

Comment: I would say that whether or not it's appropriate to use a sproc and/or make the message dynamic is dependent on lots of other circumstantial factors - the need to defend against SQL injection is not, however.

Comment: @AntP The message already contains dynamic content - OP is just building it in a very silly way. I agree with the SQL injection problem but, if we're going that direction, we should also point out other issues.

Comment: The message contains parameterised content, yes, but that doesn't imply a need for the entire message copy to come from a secondary data store - whether or not that is appropriate is really dependent on the circumstances of the application and development environment.

Comment: @AntP Ok. I disagree.

Comment: On what basis? Parameterising the parameters properly is a matter of security, whether or not to store the entire copy in a database is a matter of preference and practical need. In many environments storing your copy in a SQL database for no particular reason will give you huge flexibility penalties (particularly if e.g. your DB is managed by another team/department).